# Uploading large email attachments to S3 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, mandrill

I'm using [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com) and [Griddler](http://griddler.io/) to receive and parse inbound emails to an app hosted on Heroku.

I also handle file uploads via UI (browser) using javascript direct uploads to S3, and everything works great.

Now I'd like to handle email attachments and upload them to S3. The catch is that now I have to do it on the backend, since there's no UI, right?

Everything works great for small files, but for larger ones (Mandrill can handle up to ~= 25MB files) I get [Heroku's dreaded H12 errors](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout).

Moving to delayed jobs doesn't seem like a viable alternative due to [Heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

Any insight is much appreciated!